# How compare performance of LuaJIT vs JavaScriptCore, for a bridge to Objective-C?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, performance-testing, scripting-bridge, luajit

I’m writing a few unit tests for an Objective-C <-> LuaJIT bridge, the idea is to compare the performance of LuaJIT against JavaScriptCore and make the test fail when JS has better execution time than LuaJit at some specific tasks.

**What tasks?**

- a for loop that calculates a sum.

  [[Lua](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L923)] [[JS](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L967)]
- passing a dictionary and an array to the virtual machine, cloning the object, and returning the new object back to ObjC.

  [[Dictionary access Lua](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L934)][[Dictionary access JS](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L978)][[Array access Lua](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L943)][[Array access JS](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L987)]
- deep copying a dictionary containing arrays, dictionaries and values

  [[Deep copy Lua](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L952)][[Deep copy JS](https://github.com/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.m#L996)]

**hmm.. seriously why?**

I just want to switch back to developing games and keep updating LuaJIT with each new release, so that when the tests fail I can roll back to the previous version or do whatever be needed to have the fastest implementation of Lua running in the VM.

**ok… and the question?**

The [tests are failing randomly](https://travis-ci.org/rraallvv/ObjC-Lua/builds), some times it’s LuaJIT the fastest, sometimes it’s JS. The only reason that came to mind for that erratic behavior is that the garbage collector is messing with the execution times.

**Is there a way to force the garbage collector do it’s thing on each iteration for both engines?**

An alternative is to have a sample of N interactions and find the [Finite Mixture Model](https://github.com/CVLearner/Mixture-of-Gaussians) with the two means for the execution time, the one when the script runs in “normal” mode, and the execution time when the GC is activated to compare the performance of both engines accordingly.

**sounds to much of a hassle**

Maybe, I just want a silver bullet to kill slower scripting engines, and what else that compare them with the the native implementation of JavaScript on OS X and iOS

Comment: _"Is there a way to force the garbage collector do it’s thing on each iteration for both engines?"_ Yes, you can turn it off.